# Dynamic filtering/ masking in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame containing employee information like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Id':[1,2,3,4],
    'Name':['Joe','Henry','Sam','Max'],
    'Salary':[70000,80000,60000,90000],
    'ManagerId':[3,4,np.nan,np.nan]
})

   Id   Name  Salary  ManagerId
0   1    Joe   70000        3.0
1   2  Henry   80000        4.0
2   3    Sam   60000        NaN
3   4    Max   90000        NaN
```

What I need to do is to filter employees having their salary exceed his manager's (in this case Joe since his salary is larger than his manager, Sam).

```
0   1    Joe   70000        3.0
```

Because of the relation between Id and Manager Id, I think I can use loops as the last resort, but that seems to be really manual and looks ugly too. I wonder that if I can do this with masking. As a beginner,  I can only do simple masking where the condition is static so far, like to filter employees that have salary exceeding 60000. But in this case, the condition for each employee is different from each other.

I have no idea what this technique is called so I just made up the title.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is match `ManagerID` by `Salary` by `Id`, so possible compare for greater and filter:

```
df = df[df['Salary'].gt(df['ManagerID'].map(df.set_index(['Id'])['Salary']))]
print (df)
   Id Name  Salary  ManagerID
0   1  Joe   70000        3.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['ManagerID'].map(df.set_index(['Id'])['Salary']))
0    60000.0
1    90000.0
2        NaN
3        NaN
Name: ManagerID, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Maybe not noticeable on such a small dataset, but on larger ones prepending a less expensive condition on the presence of `ManagerID` should help with performance: `df[df['ManagerID'].notnull() & df['Salary'].gt(df['ManagerID'].map(df.set_index(['Id'])['Salary']))]`

Comment: @Max - I got you, but in my opinion if test for higher then it is always `False` for misisng values, so here is not necessary test it.

Comment: Indeed running with 100K rows and performance is the same